# How to truncate two uuid and generate new uuid in scala

Tags: java, scala

for example:

```
  val uuid1 = UUID.fromString("38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d")
  val uuid2 = UUID.fromString("475c4380-a8a4-11e5-c000-000000000000")
```

my output should be combination of both.

```
 output =   475c4380-a8a4-11e5 + b23e-10b96e4ef00d = 475c4380-a8a4-11e5-b23e-10b96e4ef00d
```

Comment: you say  output =   475c4380-a8a4-11e5 + b23e-10b96e4ef00d = 475c4380-a8a4-11e5-b23e-10b96e4ef00d
is there a reason why you take the first part of the second uuid with the second part of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two UUIDs, you need to convert those to strings, get subtrings, then create a new UUID:

```
output = UUID.fromString( uuid1.toString.substring(0,18) + uuid2.toString.substring(19) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is just to use UUID implementation and build a new uuid

```
  val uuid1 = UUID.fromString("38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d")
  val uuid2 = UUID.fromString("475c4380-a8a4-11e5-c000-000000000000")

  println( new UUID(uuid2.getMostSignificantBits, uuid1.getLeastSignificantBits).toString )
```